# Comsol-Adding "eps" to avoid division by zero

Tags: divide-by-zero, comsol

I am confused by not being able to solve this equation in Comsol

This is equation I mention:

```
1-2*sqrt(Lf/pi)*integrate((1)/sqrt(Lf^2-x^2)*(1+0.3*(1-x/Lf)/(1+Lf/0.1)),x,0,Lf)
```

If I write it in *ODE* and run, Comsol will notice message error (*division by zero*)

If I add `eps` right after like this `(Lf^2 -x^2 +eps)`, Comsol runs ok but result I get absolutely wrong

Any idea about my problem ?